# Stack overflow exception when creating interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface, stack-overflow

I'm using C# .NET Framework console application. I'm creating my own interface but I am getting a stack overflow exception. Can someone explain to me why it is happening? Here is my code:

```
namespace Interfaces
{
    interface IWorker
    {
        string name { get; set; }
        string surname { get; set; }
        uint age { get; set; }
    }
    class TeamLeader : IWorker
    {
        public string name { get => name; set => name = value; }

        public string surname { get => surname; set => surname = value; }

        public uint age { get => age; set => age = value; }
        public override string ToString()
        {

            return $"Name: {name} Surname: {surname} Age: {age}";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TeamLeader tm = new TeamLeader();
            tm.name = "John";
            tm.surname = "Wick";
            tm.age = 22;
            Console.WriteLine( tm.ToString() ); 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to this short ways to write get and set stuff. My background is C++, it's my first time using these syntax. In my opinion they are the ones that making the error.

Comment: `public uint age { get => age; set => age = value; }`: the property reads and writes *itself* change into `public uint age {get; set;}`

Comment: Simplify the properties to `public string name { get; set; }` and consider using common practice of having a capital letter for the name;

Answer (score 2):

The `set` write the value to itself and create a loop of `set` forever. This creates `StackOverflow` exception.

Try this a `private` property

```
class TeamLeader : IWorker
{
    private string _name;
    public string name { get => _name; set => _name= value; }
    ......
}
```

or just

```
class TeamLeader : IWorker
{

    public string name { get ; set ; }
    ......
}
```

Comment: Or just `{ get; set; }`

Comment: or make more readable like this :public string name { get; set; }

Comment: Yes it's a good practice to make properties starts with capitals. sorry